# Canonical get active file code throwing FileNotFound exception

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Many other answers led me to this wonderful snippet, which claims to get the currently active file in Eclipse:

```java
IWorkbenchPart workbenchPart = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
    .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart(); 
IFile file = (IFile) workbenchPart.getSite().getPage().getActiveEditor()
    .getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
if (file == null) throw new FileNotFoundException();
```

I fully believe it works based on results from those questions, however, it always throws a FileNotFoundException for me.

How can this be? Is there another way to get the active file?

Note: `org.eclipse.core.resources` and `org.eclipse.core.runtime` are both in my dependency list, so IAdaptable should work just fine. This was an issue in another question.

Comment: This depends a lot of what the editor input is. What class does the `getEditorInput()` call return?

Comment: Using `getClass().getName()`, it seems the class is `org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput`. Which is unexpected - I was expecting something related to the Java editor perspective.

Comment: `FileStoreEditorInput` does not adapt to IFile and may represent a file which is not in the workspace (so can't be an IFile). Which editor is this?

Comment: The vanilla Java editor. Ideally I was hoping to have it work for any editor (or file, per se) in the future, but just Java for now. How can a file be open in Eclipse but may not be in the workspace?

Comment: You can drag a file from anywhere on to Eclipse to open it, although the editor will usually not have full functionality. The editor input will usually implement at least one of `IFileEditorInput`, `IPathEditorEditor`, `IURIEditorInput`.

Comment: How terribly confusing. I notice all those can eventually be worked down to their absolute paths - but this would require an exorbitant amount of sniffing and despite that would not work for general cases. Are you aware of any other higher-level way to get paths, since Eclipse _must_ have this, regardless of the `*EditorInput`? Or what steps I could take next?

Comment: Added answer with some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input to an editor does not have to support adapting to `IFile`. The input will usually implement one or more of `IFileEditorInput`, `IPathEditorInput`, `IURIEditorInput` and `ILocationProvider`.

This code will find the `IFile` or `IPath` if possible:

```java
/**
 * Get a file from the editor input if possible.
 *
 * @param input The editor input
 * @return The file or <code>null</code>
 */
public static IFile getFileFromEditorInput(final IEditorInput input)
{
  if (input == null)
    return null;

  if (input instanceof IFileEditorInput)
    return ((IFileEditorInput)input).getFile();

  final IPath path = getPathFromEditorInput(input);
  if (path == null)
    return null;

  return ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(path);
}


/**
 * Get the file path from the editor input.
 *
 * @param input The editor input
 * @return The path or <code>null</code>
 */
public static IPath getPathFromEditorInput(final IEditorInput input)
{
  if (input instanceof ILocationProvider)
    return ((ILocationProvider)input).getPath(input);

  if (input instanceof IURIEditorInput)
   {
     final URI uri = ((IURIEditorInput)input).getURI();
     if (uri != null)
      {
        final IPath path = URIUtil.toPath(uri);
        if (path != null)
          return path;
      }
   }

  if (input instanceof IFileEditorInput)
   {
     final IFile file = ((IFileEditorInput)input).getFile();
     if (file != null)
       return file.getLocation();
   }

  return null;
}
```